# Calculate conversion using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregation

Suppose that there is `activities` table with two columns: string `action` and `created_at` timestamp. And there is only two possible values in action column `visit` or `signup`.

I want to see % of signups per visit for each day. Like:

```
Date       |  Conversion
--------------------------
2013-01-01 |  30%
2013-01-02 |  27%
2013-01-03 |  15%
2013-01-04 |  22%
```

Is it possible with a single SQL query?

Comment: You just want to see in select statement or want to store this in table like this

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server, this should work:

```
SELECT coalesce(v.y, s.y) y, coalesce(v.m, s.m) m, coalesce(v.d, s.d) d, 
    100.0 * isnull(s.num, 0) / (isnull(s.num, 0) + isnull(v.num, 0)) conversion  
FROM
(
    SELECT datepart(YEAR, [date]) y, datepart(m, [date]) m,datepart(d, [date]) d, 
        count(action) num
    FROM actions
    WHERE action = 'visit'
    GROUP BY datepart(YEAR, [date]), datepart(m, [date]), datepart(d, [date])
) v
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT datepart(YEAR, [date]) y, datepart(m, [date]) m,datepart(d, [date]) d, 
        count(action) num
    FROM actions
    WHERE action = 'signup'
    GROUP BY datepart(YEAR, [date]), datepart(m, [date]), datepart(d, [date])
) s
ON v.y = s.y AND v.m = s.m AND v.d = s.d
```

I leave string concatenation, rounding and general robustness as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server 2005+, you could try the following approach:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Conversion = signup * 100.0 / (signup + visit)
FROM (
  SELECT
    Date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, created_at), 0),
    action
  FROM activities
) AS a
PIVOT (
  COUNT(action) FOR action IN (visit, signup)
) AS p
;
```

The `Date` expression strips the `created_at` timestamp off the time part. In SQL Server 2008 and later versions, it can be replaced with the much cleaner and more efficient operation of casting to the `date` type:

```
Date = CAST(created_at AS date)
```